# Avoid pictures from loading and capturing the URL in WebView Android

Tags: android, url, webview, load, image

How to avoid all the pictures from loading, in `WebView`?
Also I need to get the URL of those pictures.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing for API level 11 or later, you can use the [`WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) to handle the request for loading an image. The second parameter of the method is the URL of the resource.

You would have to return the [`WebResourceResponse`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html) object, possibly a placeholder/error image if you do not want the original image to be loaded.